# Do predictors in logistic regression need to be stationary?

Tags: regression, logistic, stationarity

For linear regression with time series predictors, it is widely accepted that both dependent and independent variables must be stationary. The reason is that we need to assume that the errors are normal with constant variance so that we can make inference about the coefficients. That leads to $Y - a - bX$ being stationary, and therefore either $X$ and $Y$ are stationary or they are co-integrated.

Now for logistic regression with time series predictors, there is no condition on the variance of the error (nor that it has to be normal). So the argument that is valid for linear regression is no longer applicable for logistic regression.

Do we still need the independent variable(s) to be stationary (or co-integrated) in a logistic regression? And why?

Comment: " Y - a - bX", is this suppose to be $Y=a+bX$ or is it "$Y$, $a$, and $bX$"?

Comment: Y - a -bX = Error which is assumed to be normal with fixed variance, so that is stationary.

Comment: In my experience, "stationary" is only used with regard to time series. Do you have a time series? Or am I missing something?

Comment: Yes, the predictor is an econometric time series.

Comment: I’m struggling to understand what it even means for these variables to be stationary. At least for the outcome, the whole reason to do a regression is an expectation that the outcome has different distributions at various values of the features. Could you please say exactly what you mean?

Comment: Dave: The way I look at it is that when you do linear regression for instance, each observation is the realization of a random variable. And those random variables are assumed to be independent. When the predictors are realizations from a time series (meaning that the index is time), the set of those random variables indexed with time become a stochastic process (and those random variables are generally not independent) and that is where the stationarity makes sense. However, people do not make those details explicit most of the time.

Comment: It sounds like you might be describing autocorrelation. Could you point to the property you want from your regression and the assumptions needed for that property to hold (such as the Gauss-Markov conditions giving desirable estimator properties)?

Comment: Dave: For linear regression, you assume that the errors are normal i.i.d, which (implicitly) implies both that there is no auto-correlation and the staionarity. As far as I know, the assumptions of normality and i.i.d allow us to find confidence intervals for the coefficient.
For logistic regression, none of those assumptions about the error term are made and my question is whether we still have to have (implicitly) stationary predictors.

Comment: Even in the linear regression setting, I’m not seeing the connection between the time series nature of the features and the time series nature of the errors. Could you please explain your rationale?

Comment: I’m also not sold on the claim that it is widely accepted that the features need to be stationary. The regression conditions on the feature values, and once you condition on something, its distribution does not matter. You know the value. There is no more uncertainty.

Comment: Dave: If the predictors are time series (i.e. indexed with time), it makes the errors also time series since time is the index. It is an assumption of linear regression that the errors are i.i.d and normally distributed with constant variance which implies in particular that the errors are a stationary process (a white noise process actually).

Comment: And what if the features are not stationary but the errors are $iid$ Gaussian? I’m just not seeing why the feature stationarity matters. Do you have a reference? I’d be interested in the exact claim.

Comment: Dave: In that case, we must have co-integrated variables or we risk to have spurious regression. Look up those two terms where the theory is well explained for the case of linear regression.

Comment: 1. I can easily predict ice cream sales in a location by using a series of daily temperatures at that location (and some other features); that's hardly a stationary predictor, thanks to seasonal effects, but it works.  2. Normally-distributed errors is not an assumption of linear regression, as has been pointed out on this site many times.

Comment: 1) Yes because temperature and sales are co-integrated (some linear combination is stationary)
2) Normality isn't strictly needed, but it makes inference much easier and that is why it is often assumed if I'm not mistaken.

Comment: Why is it such a given that ice cream sales and temperature are cointegrated? (I’m not even convinced that they are so correlated.)

Comment: I don't have empirical evidence.

Comment: Then I am confused about your comment that ice cream sales and temperature are cointegrated.

Comment: 1. Actually, *usually* sample sizes are large enough for asymptotics to take over with regression, so Normality isn't needed, *usually*, for inferential purposes.  Such has been my experience at any rate.  2. Ice cream sales and temperature are correlated, but mostly because a) it's warmer in summer and b) it's cooler when it rains.  I don't expect 30 degrees C and 32 degrees C in Sarasota, Florida to be meaningfully different, though.

Comment: @jbwoman Agree with both points.
The question I raised is in a context where the predictor is quarterly GDP with less than 100 data points. The logistic regression is to model upgrade/downgrade for some bonds/issuers.

Answer (score 1):

Stationarity is a property of a random process. In regression modeling, the covariates/predictors are considered fixed and non-random. That is not to say that they do not have random properties in the context of experimental design, but in traditional regression modeling, such as logistic regression, the modeling strategy is to model the *conditional* distribution of the response as a function of the predictors - hence why they are called *predictors*.

You should be aware this is a separate discussion from confounding and models for dependent data (like GEE or GLMMs). (Note: *stationarity*, such as for an error term, does not mean a model for independent data is correct, rather it means that very simple models for dependent data can be used). Furthermore, when I say models for "dependent data" I refer to the conditional distribution of the response, after adjustment for predictors.

You can easily think of many modeling applications where the "X" variable is a non-stationary process, and the naive inference ranges from clear, to nuanced, to completely ambiguous. For instance, you might look at a time series of blood pressure predicting the use of a blood pressure lowering medication. In this case, medication use is associated with a higher blood pressure specifically due to confounding by indication. On one hand, it is correct to say people using this medication tend to have higher blood pressure than those who do not. On the other hand, it is completely incorrect to say the blood pressure medication is ineffective.